# Are reddish egg whites safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, eggs, egg-whites

5 minutes ago I cracked an egg and was surprised with an orange, reddish egg white. It has the color of light fish sauce. The chalazae is red. I would assume that the reddish color comes from the blood. The egg smells fine, no sulfurous smell. Before cracking the egg, the shell was intact. Is this egg safe to eat?

I know the rule "in doubt, throw it out" but I'm interested if the egg is still edible.

[image]

Comment: That looks like a fertilized chicken egg: https://www.google.com/search?q=fertilized+chicken+egg&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CBwQsARqFQoTCMuYnuW2jckCFQR4Jgodz2ENrw&biw=921&bih=525 Despite being pretty rare from the grocery store nowadays, they're generally regarded as safe to eat.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger, I disagree. Looks like a blood clot, which can happen during the formation of the egg.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger The little white disk doesn't look like a donut as the internet suggest in case of a fertilized egg.

Comment: I've eaten eggs like that and I'm still here. Anecdotal evidence only and no safety is implied, but it wouldn't have even crossed my mind not to eat them like that

Comment: 1. Did this egg come from a batch? What about the others? 2) Egg yokes get color from the chicken feed - some times they are colored intentionally. This will depend on your location (e.g. if it's legally allowed)

Comment: @JanDoggen The egg whites from the other eggs in the egg carton were normal-colored. I can't imagine that the coloring was intentional. The eggs were bought in Germany.

Answer (score 1):

Intact and good-looking eggs are generally safe to eat -- any spoilage very quickly results in horrible smell. The thing you're seeing might actually be a very tiny remain of something related with embryo (there's a tiny red piece of embryo in all eggs, you just have to search a bit) or a colored piece of internal egg-white structure (I heard that grass- and mineral-rich food may cause coloring like that), just bigger for some reason.

Anyway, I'm regularly eating eggs like that since childhood and I'm still here. It's safe.

(PS. I never tried to drink anything like this uncooked, but there are many other reasons not to try that. :D)

Answer (score 1):

They're [meat spots](https://poultrykeeper.com/egg-problems/meat-spots-in-eggs/), and safe (though unpleasant) to eat.

Answer (score 0):

Pinkish egg whites are a sign of spoilage.  You may not die from it, but it could make you mildly or severely ill depending on what is causing the spoilage (just age/deterioration, or how much bacteria is growing in it and what type of bacteria).